# using pgpool doesn't see a list of variables into group_var directory

Tags: infrastructure, ansible, provisioning

I am using ***Ansible*** + ***Vagrant*** to create my infrastructure or make a little simulation of I wish. It installing postgres and creating a ssh directory to store the differents keys for each host.

It is my project structure:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── cluster_hosts
├── group_vars
│   ├── host_master
│   ├── host_pgpool
│   ├── host_slave1
│   └── postgresql
├── roles
│   ├── postgresql
│   │   ├── files
│   │   ├── handlers
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   └── ssh_agent
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── site.yml
```

It is the **cluster_hosts** declaration:

```
host_master ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.10 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
host_slave1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.11 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
host_slave2 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.12 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
host_pgpool ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.13 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant

[ssh]
host_master
host_pgpool
host_slave1

[pg_pool]
host_pgpool

[database]
host_master
host_pgpool
host_slave1
host_slave2
```

It is my group_vars files:

### host_master

```
known_hosts:
    - 192.168.1.11
    - 192.168.1.12
```

### host_pgpool

```
known_hosts:
    - 192.168.1.11
    - 192.168.1.12
```

### host_slave1

```
known_hosts:
    - 192.168.1.12
```

And here is my ***site.yml***:

```
---
# The main playbook to deploy the cluster

# setup database
- hosts: database
  sudo: True
  tags:
    - setup_db
  roles:
    - postgresql

# setup ssh
- hosts: all
  sudo: True
  tags:
    - setup_ssh
  roles:
    - ssh_agent
```

And here is the ***ssh_agent role***:

```
---
- name: Install sshpass
  apt: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - sshpass
    - rsync

- name: Create ssh directory
  sudo_user: postgres
  command: mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/ creates=/var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/

- name: Generate known hosts
  sudo_user: postgres
  shell: ssh-keyscan -t rsa {{ item }} >> /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/known_hosts
  with_items: 
    - "{{ known_hosts }}"

- name: Generate id_rsa key
  sudo_user: postgres
  command: ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -C "" -f /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_rsa

- name: Add authorized_keys
  command: sshpass -p postgres ssh-copy-id -i /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/id_rsa.pub postgres@{{ item }}
  sudo_user: postgres
  with_items: 
    - "{{ known_hosts }}"

- name: Owner postgresql
  command: chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/.ssh/ -R
```

ok, Now when I run:

```
ansible-playbook -i cluster_hosts site.yml --tags setup_ssh
```

I get an error in the ***Generate known hosts*** task :

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [host_pgpool]
ok: [host_slave2]
ok: [host_slave1]
ok: [host_master]

TASK: [ssh_agent | Install sshpass] ******************************************* 
ok: [host_slave1] => (item=sshpass,rsync)
ok: [host_master] => (item=sshpass,rsync)
ok: [host_pgpool] => (item=sshpass,rsync)
ok: [host_slave2] => (item=sshpass,rsync)

TASK: [ssh_agent | Create ssh directory] ************************************** 
skipping: [host_master]
skipping: [host_slave2]
skipping: [host_slave1]
skipping: [host_pgpool]

TASK: [ssh_agent | Generate known hosts] ************************************** 
fatal: [host_slave1] => One or more undefined variables: 'known_hosts' is undefined
fatal: [host_master] => One or more undefined variables: 'known_hosts' is undefined
fatal: [host_slave2] => One or more undefined variables: 'known_hosts' is undefined
fatal: [host_pgpool] => One or more undefined variables: 'known_hosts' is undefined

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/robe/site.retry

host_master                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
host_pgpool                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
host_slave1                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   
host_slave2                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

I don't understand why this error? if each variable is declared in group_vars (host_master, host_pgpool, host_slave1).

Is my yml syntax wrong? I think that maybe it is the problem but I see that it is right for me?

Answer (score 2):

By default, ansible does not read all files in `group_vars/`; it only reads `group_vars/all` (or `group_vars/all.yml`; incidentally, I've found it more convenient to add the `.yml` extension to vars files). You need to tell it to read the files you want using `vars_files` in your `site.yml`, like this:

```
- hosts: database
  sudo: True
  tags:
    - setup_db
  roles:
    - postgresql
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/host_master
```

Comment: I'm with you on adding .yml extensions to vars files. They are indeed in YAML format and having the .yml extension makes it easier for your text editor to choose the correct syntax highlighting, among other things.   I haven't been able to find any answers on why the best practices doc treats vars files like a special case.